# HTML from _includes not showing where included using Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I'm hosting a personal site using GitHub Pages.

I'd like to reduce HTML code duplication by taking advantage of GitHub's builtin Jekyll templating functionality. For instance, putting `footer.html` into a `/_includes` directory for reuse on every future page.

I also *happen* to enjoy organising my files, so I put my 'real' `index.html` inside a `/html` sub-directory, along with all my other html files. GitHub pages doesn't like this, so I have used a [dummy `index.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository) in the root directory so that the site will be loaded by GitHub.

Whenever I use:

```
---
---
```

at the top of a `.html` file **within** my `/html` directory, they rather strangely get rendered as text at the top. In fact, so do my {% includes foo.html %} calls.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 'dummy' `index.html` workaround, you will also need to enable Liquid in the root there by placing:

```
---
---
```

at the top of your dummy `index.html`:

```
index.html (dummy) <- double '---' here
html/
├─ index.html
├─ foo.html <- double '---' here to use {% includes bah.html %}
_includes/
├─ bah.html
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459332/jekyll-includes-not-working-in-github-pages-without-a-template) helped the penny drop.